# I am getting a ClientException: ffmpeg not found error when in discord.py

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py

Here is the exception: ClientException: ffmpeg was not found.

The bot is hosted in replit, it was working fine all this time, this is a new thing.

What must I do?

```
async def play_music(self, ctx):
        vc = discord.utils.get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
        self.now_playing = self.music_queue[0][0]['title']
        self.now_playing_url = self.music_queue[0][0]['url']
        m_url = self.music_queue[0][0]['source']

        # try to connect to voice channel if you are not already connected
        try:
            vc = await self.music_queue[0][1].connect()
        except discord.errors.ClientException:
            await vc.move_to(self.music_queue[0][1])
        print(self.music_queue)

        vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(m_url, **self.ffmpeg_options), after=lambda e: self.play_next(ctx))
        # remove the first element as you are currently playing it
        self.music_queue.pop(0)
```

Comment: can we have code?

Comment: vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(m_url, **self.ffmpeg_options), after=lambda e: self.play_next(ctx))
This line raising the exception.

Comment: I have added the full code too, please check it out!

Answer (score 0):

Try seeing this it may solve your problem in replit
https://repl.it/talk/learn/OPUS-SUPPORT-FOR-DISCORD-MUSIC-BOTS/37015

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help! I just found out that ffmpeg is not supported in replit anymore. Stated here: [link](https://replit.com/talk/ask/Installing-FFmpeg/28721). Thank you for the help again!

I hosted my bot on another service which allows ffmpeg.

Comment: Thats very old news , i too have my bot which was using ffmpeg and was hosted on replit

Comment: I tried installing ffmpeg-static using node, but it still did not work.

Comment: I switched to another hosting service, it has more resources, so I will probably not use replit again. Thank you so much for your help though!

Answer (score -1):

Try install FFmpeg pip module and import it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried installing it, as well as importing it. It simply doesn't work, though it has been installed!

Comment: Hey, edited the post, please check out what's wrong, the same code used to work before, somehow, it's not working now.